# when i am tried install git in ubuntu terminal getting malformed error

Tags: command-line, apt, git, jenkins

```
: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_apt_releases_hashicorp_comjammy-jammy.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

when i am try to install git in ubuntu terminal i am getting this error
my "pwd" is shown (home/ubuntu) and "ls" showing like this (Bigboss  jenkins.io.key  jenkins.io.key.1  jenkins.io.key.2  test)
sources.list.d/(showing no such files in directory)

i am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.19.0-1026-aws x86_64)

i am biginner for this course help me out anyone pls

Comment: What int the error do you not understand ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us `head -n 3 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_apt_releases_hashicorp_comjammy-jammy.list  /etc/apt/sources.list`. Clearly, line 1 of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_apt_releases_hashicorp_comjammy-jammy.list` has unacceptable syntax. Also, your question content and question formatting is suboptimal. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting